# Calendar User inputting dates?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I would like to add user input as in they enter the dates so I can do calculations on it later. Instead of setting the date like I did below I am at a loss of how this is done if anyone could help or point me in the right direction that would be great.

```
Calendar dueDate1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar dueDate2 = Calendar.getInstance();

dueDate1.set(2015,0,1);
dueDate2.set(2014,0,1);

long time1 = dueDate1.getTimeInMillis();
long time2 = dueDate2.getTimeInMillis();

time = (time1 - time2);

long answer = time/1000/60/60/24/365;
long days = time/1000/60/60/24;


System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Difference between 2015,0,1 & 2014,0,1");
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Years difference " + answer);
System.out.println("Days difference " + days);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user to input data to your program from the console, the easiest way to achieve this is to use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Also, date calculations will become much easier if you use the [Joda time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) -- or if you're on Java 8, its redesigned date&time API, instead of "old API classes" like Calendar and Date.

Here's a example using `Scanner` and Joda time:

```
private void showDateDiffs() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    DateTime dueDate1 = new DateTime()
            .withYear(getInput(sc, "year", "due date 1"))
            .withMonthOfYear(getInput(sc, "month", "due date 1"))
            .withDayOfMonth(getInput(sc, "day", "due date 1"));

    DateTime dueDate2 = new DateTime()
            .withYear(getInput(sc, "year", "due date 2"))
            .withMonthOfYear(getInput(sc, "month", "due date 2"))
            .withDayOfMonth(getInput(sc, "day", "due date 2"));

    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    System.out.println(String.format("\nDifference between %s & %s\n",
            df.format(dueDate1.toDate()), df.format(dueDate2.toDate())));
    System.out.println("Years difference "
            + Years.yearsBetween(dueDate2.toLocalDate(),
                    dueDate1.toLocalDate()).getYears());
    System.out.println("Days difference "
            + Days.daysBetween(dueDate2.toLocalDate(),
                    dueDate1.toLocalDate()).getDays());
}

private static int getInput(Scanner sc, String timeUnit,
        String dateIdentifier) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Input %s for %s", timeUnit,
            dateIdentifier));
    return sc.nextInt();
}
```